# Flutter Onpressed function to change the text from black to green once pressed and returned to black when no click

Tags: flutter

Need the button to make the text green when cllicking the button

```
                   'child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Make Green'),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    onPressed: (){
                     // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
                     
                    },`
```

i tried                 `color: _wasPressed ? Colors.green : Colors.black`

Answer (score 1):

- First off you will need to be in a stateful widget.
- Secondly, in your onPressed you will setState for your _wasPressed variable which will trigger a rerender of this widget

```
...

bool _wasPressed = false;


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text(
                'Make Green',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: _wasPressed ? Colors.green : Colors.black
                )
            ),
            onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                    _wasPressed = !_wasPressed;
                })
            }
        )
    );
}
```